# pngcairo does not display axis Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, cairo

I've just installed gnuplot and pngcairo via brew on my mac and when I plot data or a function the axis are not displayed (although it displays the graph).

If I change the terminal to png or svg or anything else, it works perfectly but once i set my terminal to pngcairo again it focuses on the graph.

Any ideas to resolve that problem ? (This plot and data comes from gnuplotting.org)

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
#
# Creates a version of a plot, which looks nice for inclusion on web pages
#
# AUTHOR: Hagen Wierstorf


reset

# png
#set terminal pngcairo 
#set output 'nice_web_plot.png' 

set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0,0 right
# define axis
# remove border on top and right and set color to gray
set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1
set border 3 back ls 11
set tics nomirror
# define grid
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12

# color definitions
set style line 1 lc rgb '#8b1a0e' pt 1 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # --- red
set style line 2 lc rgb '#5e9c36' pt 6 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # --- green

set key bottom right

set xlabel 'x axis label'
set ylabel 'y axis label'
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]

plot 'data.dat' u 1:2 t 'Example line' w lp ls 1, \
 ''                  u 1:3 t 'Another example' w lp ls 2
```

[image: This plot and data comes from gnuplotting.org]

Comment: Can you post the code you used to make the plot, and the gnuplot version?

Comment: I edited to the post, I'm using OS X 10.8.3 and gnuplot 4.6.2 for info.

Answer (score 2):

## How to solve the problem :

type this in your terminal

```
brew rm cairo pango gnuplot
brew edit pango
```

change url and sha256 to

```
url 'http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.29/pango-1.29.5.tar.xz'
sha256 '578c38de8450baa61d651e96049d2710f242bda3c47afc2d84773cbafeed775a'
```

then re install gnuplot

```
brew install gnuplot --cairo --wx --use-clang
```

It should now work (this solution was found here: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11901)

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you:

```
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set xtics axis
set ytics axis
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, it doesn't I tried that as well.

Comment: @Anoracx another idea: maybe your tics simply dont show on the axis because the default distance for the tics is 1 and your plot goes only from 0 to 1. Try `set xtics 0.2`